# How can I make side nav active if two-component belong to the same nav?

Tags: angular, angular8

1. I have two components like one is **project-list** and the second is **project-details**.
2. When I click on project nav the side nav is active but when I click on the project list add button. The navigation becomes inactive.
3. I below the screenshot for better understand.
4. The first component is the project list and the second is project details.

[image: Project List Image]

[image: Project Details Image]

Comment: You can add an OR condition in that navigation button route  so that whenever routes related to that page are active it will show active.

Comment: Project details component routing is not added in the navbar. I calling that component on button click.